# Using VBA macro to open, lock cells, then protect workbooks, but can still edit LOCKED, PROTECTED cells

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I need to update many old 2003 .xls files to lock and protect a block of cells to keep people from opening the cells and copying out the header information. This is a one-time process, unfortunately, I can't just block off\restrict access to the files.

Using Excel 2010 in compatibility mode I have cobbled together a macro that opens the files, locks the cells, protects the worksheets, then saves and closes the file and moves on to the next file. However, when I manually re-open the files I am still able to copy from the locked cells. Worksheet is showing as protected, when I unlock the cells they show as locked AND they show select locked cells is checked. Any ideas?

```
Sub Lockdown()

Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim sFileSpec As String
Dim sPathSpec As String
Dim sFoundFile As String

sPathSpec = "C:\Archive\PF\"
sFileSpec = "*.xls"

sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
Do While sFoundFile <> ""
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
    With wBk
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Unprotect 'Some worksheets have protection without password
            ws.Unprotect Password:="A1234" 'some worksheets have password protection
            ws.Range("A1:I10").Locked = True
            ws.Protect contents:=True
            Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Set wBk = Nothing
    Workbooks(sFoundFile).Close True
    sFoundFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `when I manually re-open the files I am still able to copy from the locked cells` - So your question is, "How do I make it so the locked cells cannot be copied from?"

Comment: Yes, how do I set the cell so that it is locked, protected, and can't be selected\copied from when the file is re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example I put together that will prevent the user from selecting ONLY the cells A1, A2, B1, and B2. However, all other cells can be selected.

```
Set myWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySht = myWkbk.Worksheets(1)
With mySht
    .Cells.Locked = False
    .Range("A1:B2").Locked = True
    .Protect contents:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give that a try.